# Alternative to Boruta function in R for Large data set

Tags: r, feature-selection

I have a data set with 90,275 rows & 60 variables. I want to do Feature engineering for this data set. Previously I used Boruta() under package Boruta for feature engineering. But seeing the size of data set,I'm feeling that Boruta() will take very long time.
Can you please suggest me some alternative to Boruta for feature engineering large data set?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer would be, it depends on your data format (type of variables) since input space for different FE/FS algorithm varies significantly.

So, please, first of all, please provide the structure of your data frame.

But for a moment, I would assume you have the following formats:
1) numerical
2) factors, characters, logical and dummy variables
3) mix of numeric and factor variable

Numerical input: PCA, LDA, anova, Pearson correlation should help you to decrease dimensionality. It works quite fast since it's numeric data

Factor & Mix: anova, tree based solutions (random forest, xgboost, cubist) by checking important variables of models. These options are quite fast as well, assuming that your data does not have too many level (i.e. variable "city" with 200 options etc).

Answer (score 0):

Boruta can be a good alternative to Boruta.  Ironic, right?

Boruta allows you to specify the tool it uses.
One of the controls is "getImp".

- If it is "getImpRFZ" then it is a z-score of mean decrease in
  accuracy from a Ranger-based forest.  Ranger tends to be faster than
  BreimanCutler.
- If it is "getImpXgboost" then it uses XGBoost, which is fast and
  handles big stuff.
- If it is "getImpExtraZ" then it uses the ExtraTrees library, which is
  supposed to be decent against big stuff as well.  Note, use ~5x the
  tree count you would in a textbook RF.
- You can also homebrew your importance function, but it should be
  pretty tough to beat XGboost.